# URL hash with drop down filter - ISOTOPE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I've check many subject on Stack Overflow, but I've not succeed to make my filter option selection work from an other page.

I make a jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/f0Ld07mv/2/

My isotope script

```
    $(function(){

  var $container = $('#plaquettes_container'),
      filters = {};


  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.plaquette_container',
    transitionDuration: 0,
  });

  // filter buttons
  $('select').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    // store filter value in object
    // i.e. filters.color = 'red'
    var group = $this.attr('data-filter-group');

    filters[ group ] = $this.find(':selected').attr('data-filter-value');
    // console.log( $this.find(':selected') )
    // convert object into array
    var isoFilters = [];
    for ( var prop in filters ) {
      isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
    }
    console.log(filters);
    var selector = isoFilters.join('');
    $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
    return false;
  });

      $('section_plaquettes ul>li').click(function() {
          var $this = $(this);
          var group = $this.parent().data('filter-group');
          filters[ group ] = $this.data('filter-value'); 
          var isoFilters = [];
            for ( var prop in filters ) {
              isoFilters.push( filters[ prop ] )
            }
            console.log(filters);
            var selector = isoFilters.join('');
            $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
            return false;
      });

});
```

I dont know how to use URL Hash with my 2 drop down menu : I found many thing from the official website : [http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/vErxX](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html) 
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html

But i dont succeed when i try to adapt for my type of isotope filter, if you guys can help me, thank you !

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/f0Ld07mv/2/

Comment: Oh you make my jsfiddle working :D that wasnt the question, i just want to add the URL Hash in to my dropdown lists

Comment: What do you mean when you say: `URL Hash` ?

Comment: I want to use my filter with link, like this http://s.codepen.io/desandro/debug/vErxXj#filter=%3Anot(.transition)
for finaly use my filter from an other page, like if i click on a like a got my page with prefiltered

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking...

Comment: Well i'm sorry ^^ I want to make a link for automatically filter my page with the good option, its more clear ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114698/discussion-between-hightline-and-hackerman).